# C# fonts as 2D points

Tags: c#, fonts

I am programming in C# and I need a way to get fonts as points in 2D. I basically want fonts converted to a mesh so that I can render it in 2D/3D. Are there any ways to do that? Or is it better to just download the meshes or something and then load them into my program.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `winforms` you can use a [`GraphicsPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from `System.Drawing.Drawing2D` to

- either acces the **Bezier** curves in the `PathPoints` and `PathTypes` data
- or, after `Flattening` the path to acces the `PathPoints` array that now makes up an array of **line segments**.

Use one of the [`GraphicsPath.AddString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142533%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) methods to create the path..!

You may also want to look into the [`GraphicsPathIterator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspathiterator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  class, which..

> Provides the ability to iterate through subpaths in a GraphicsPath and
>   test the types of shapes contained in each subpath..

Here is an example of drawing the flattened segment points:

[image]

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(400, 400);
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
using (Font f = new Font("Tahoma", 40f))
{
    g.ScaleTransform(4,4);
    gp.AddString("Y?", f.FontFamily, 0, 40f, new Point(0, 0), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    g.DrawPath(Pens.Gray, gp);
    gp.Flatten(new Matrix(), 0.2f);  // <<== *
    g.DrawPath(Pens.DarkSlateBlue, gp);
    for (int i = 0; i < gp.PathPoints.Length; i++)
    {
        PointF p = gp.PathPoints[i];
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.DarkOrange, p.X-1, p.Y - 1, 2, 2);
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```

Note the 2nd `Flatten` parameter that lets you control how tight i.e. how closely the curve is approximated by the lines. The **smaller** the value the **more** 2d points are created..

To use the unflattended path you need to combine the `PathPoints` with their respective `PathTypes`; this is basically the same as creating **Bezier** curves: Two control points go between each pair of points. The types tell you where a figure starts/ends and where a line starts or a curve..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `GlyphTypeface.GetGlyphOutline` method to return the *glyphs* which make up the curves of the lettering.   Note this is part of WPF.

MSDN:

> Returns a Geometry value describing the path for a single glyph in the font

Under the hood I suspect it is calling the native function [`GetGlyphOutline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144891(v=vs.85).aspx)

...which you could p-invoke from a WinForms/XNA app.